# jquery select span by id

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview, select, html

hello guys
some times you just loose it and you cant event remember how to search that that you lost

```
 <div>
        <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView" style="height:90%;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">Lenda</th><th scope="col">CSV Dosje</th><th scope="col">Gjendje</th><th scope="col">Dat&#235;</th><th scope="col">Njoftim</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$DefaultContent$migrationGridView$ctl02$Button1" value="Fshije" id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl02_Button1" />
                                </td><td>
                                    <a id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl02_CaseLinkButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$DefaultContent$migrationGridView$ctl02$CaseLinkButton','')" style="font-weight:bold;">mig1</a>
                                </td><td>
                                    <span id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl02_lblCSVFileName">19_71914066_2010-11-11_0849_ENG_SOFALI.csv</span>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </td><td>
                                    <span id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl02_Label2" style="color:Maroon;font-weight:bold;">Read</span>
                                </td><td>2010-12-28</td><td>
                                    <span id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl02_Label3"></span>
                                </td><td>

                                    <a id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl02_startStopLinkButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$DefaultContent$migrationGridView$ctl02$startStopLinkButton','')">Start migration</a>
                                    &nbsp;
                                    <a id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl02_checkedAllLinkButton" title="Të Kontrolluara" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$DefaultContent$migrationGridView$ctl02$checkedAllLinkButton','')">Të Kontrolluara</a>
                                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$DefaultContent$migrationGridView$ctl03$Button1" value="Fshije" id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl03_Button1" />
                                </td><td>
                                    <a id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl03_CaseLinkButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$DefaultContent$migrationGridView$ctl03$CaseLinkButton','')" style="font-weight:bold;">mig1</a>
                                </td><td>
                                    <span id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl03_lblCSVFileName">19_71914070_2010-11-11_0850_ENG_TRUDE.csv</span>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </td><td>
                                    <span id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl03_Label2" style="color:Maroon;font-weight:bold;">Read</span>
                                </td><td>2010-12-28</td><td>
                                    <span id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl03_Label3"></span>
                                </td><td>

                                    <a id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl03_startStopLinkButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$DefaultContent$migrationGridView$ctl03$startStopLinkButton','')">Start migration</a>
                                    &nbsp;
                                    <a id="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl03_checkedAllLinkButton" title="Të Kontrolluara" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$DefaultContent$migrationGridView$ctl03$checkedAllLinkButton','')">Të Kontrolluara</a>
                                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

can somebody tell me how to iterate through spans that have this string on the id 'lblCSVFileName'
and get their values

for the first row i should get 19_71914066_2010-11-11_0849_ENG_SOFALI.csv and for the second 
19_71914070_2010-11-11_0850_ENG_TRUDE.csv

:( another bad day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [attribute ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) for the ID and [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get an array of strings (the text inside each), like this:

```
var arr = $("span[id$='lblCSVFileName']").map(function() { 
            return $(this).text(); 
          }).get();
```

Or, a slightly more optimized unpublished version:

```
var arr = $("span[id$='lblCSVFileName']").map(function() { 
            return $.text([this]); 
          }).get();
```

This would get you an array of values to work with, for example:

```
["19_71914066_2010-11-11_0849_ENG_SOFALI.csv", "19_71914070_2010-11-11_0850_ENG_TRUDE.csv"...]
```

Comment: Thank you for linking to the appropriate pages.   Trying to memorize jQuery syntax and the links help to keep my memory fresh.

Comment: Beautiful answer, as always! Could you briefly explain the difference between the two versions?

Comment: @Gustav - the second version isn't documented, but saves the creation of a jQuery object...so it's much faster.

Comment: thanks Nick you just saved my day thank you brother I owe you one.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you what you need.
It gets all spans that have an ID that starts with "ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl02_".

```
$('span[id^="ctl00_DefaultContent_migrationGridView_ctl02_"]').each(function() {
  //the following will give you the text of each span
  $(this).text();
});
```

NOTE: I would add a class to each span and do a jquery select using that.